# Swift. Add attributes to multiple instances

Tags: swift, attributes, nsattributedstring

I have `arrays` containing strings of the text terms to which I want to apply a particular attribute. Here's a code snippit:

```
static var bold = [String]()
static let boldAttribs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "WorkSans-Medium", size: 19)!]
for term in bold {
    atStr.addAttributes(boldAttribs, range: string.rangeOfString(term))
}
```

This works great for single term or phrase use. But it only applies to the first use of a specific term. Is there a way, without resorting to numerical ranges, to apply the attribute to all instances of the same term? For example, make every use of "animation button" within the same string bold.

Edit: This works.

```
// `butt2` is [String]() of substrings to attribute
// `term` is String element in array, target of attributes
// `string` is complete NAString from data
// `atStr` is final
for term in butt2 {
    var pos = NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length)
    while true {
        let next = string.rangeOfString(term, options: .LiteralSearch, range: pos)
        if next.location == NSNotFound {    break   }

        pos = NSRange(location: next.location+next.length, length: string.length-next.location-next.length)

        atStr.addAttributes(butt2Attribs, range: next)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to resort to numerical ranges, but you do need to resort to a loop:

```
// atStr is mutable attributed string
// str is the input string
atStr.beginEditing()
var pos = NSRange(location: 0, length: atStr.length)
while true {
    let next = atStr.rangeOfString(target, options: .LiteralSearch, range: pos)
    if next.location == NSNotFound {
        break
    }
    atStr.addAttributes(boldAttribs, range: next)
    print(next)
    pos = NSRange(location: next.location+next.length, length: atStr.length-next.location-next.length)
}
atStr.endEditing()
```

Comment: This produces values of type Range<String.CharacterView.Index. As far as I can tell, I need to convert these to type NSRange. I've been through a pasel of postings on how to effect this but none seem to help. How frustrating that logging `next.endIndex` and `next.count` print the exact values I need to make an NSRange but I can't convert to `Ints`. BTW, no compound glyphs anywhere in my text. Thanks though, it does the job to that point.

Comment: @bpedit This should fix it, NSRange API is a little different - no "cute" built-in support from the compiler.

Comment: Not working either. `NSMutableString` has no member `range of string`. I'd realy like to use my Swift `String` there (`str` for `atStr`) but I get the same conversion issue as the first go-round.

Comment: @bpedit I copied this from a working playground snippet, it worked absolutely fine. [Here is a pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/KeZ2m5zW), copy it into a playground and check what's different between this and your program.

Comment: Yep, finally made it work, I appended my post  above. Thanks